# Gmail API socket.timeout : The read operation timed out

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail, gmail-api, gmail-imap

My program which utilizes the Python Gmail API has been encountering alot of socket.timeout errors. I am very frequently receiving the following:

```
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out
```

This error appears to be random and generally occurs with any Gmail API function. I have tried modifying the socket timeout parameter. However, changing this parameter does not seem to remove the issue. I have varied it from 1 second, 10 seconds, and 600 seconds.

```
socket.setdefaulttimeout(10)
```

Or for an httplib2.Http object:

```
def build_http(self): 
    """Builds httplib2.Http object 

    Returns: 
    A httplib2.Http object, which is used to make http requests, and which has timeout set by default. 
    To override default timeout call 

        socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout_in_sec) 

    before interacting with this method. 
    """ 
    try: 
        return httplib2.Http(timeout=10) 
    except: 
        self.GLogger.error("An error was encountered in build_http")
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        self.GLogger.exception(tb)
        return False
```

The following code is used to initialize the Gmail API service.

```
def gmailAPIInitialize(self):
    try:
        self.waitForInternet()
        self.GLogger.info("Initializing the Gmail API Service")
        creds = None
        # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
        # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
        # time.
        if self.reprocess is True: 
            token_pickle_file = 'Gmail_token_2.pickle'
            credentials_file = 'Gmail_credentials_2.json'
        else:
            token_pickle_file = 'Gmail_token_1.pickle'
            credentials_file = 'Gmail_credentials_1.json'
            
        if os.path.exists(token_pickle_file):
            with open(token_pickle_file, 'rb') as token:
                creds = pickle.load(token)
        # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                    credentials_file, SCOPES)
                creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            # Save the credentials for the next run
            with open(token_pickle_file, 'wb') as token:
                pickle.dump(creds, token)
   
        #service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds, cache_discovery=False)
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds, cache_discovery=False)
        self.gmailAPIService  = service
        self.GLogger.info("Successfully initialized the Gmail API Service")
        return True
    except:
        self.GLogger.error("An error was encountered while attempting to initialize the Gmail API")
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        self.GLogger.exception(tb)
        return False
```

Again, pretty much any function will trigger this issue. But here are some examples:

Thread List:

```
def gmailAPIMessageLabelSearchThreads(self, labelList, userID="me", allPages=False, reverseOrder=False):
    try:
        self.GLogger.info("Attempting to search email threads with labelList (" + str(labelList)+ ") and userID (" +str(userID)+ ")")
        service = self.gmailAPIService
        if service is None:
            logging.error('Gmail Service not initialized')
            return False
        response = service.users().threads().list(userId=userID, labelIds=labelList,maxResults=500, fields="threads(id),nextPageToken").execute()
        messages = []
        if 'messages' in response:
            messages.extend(response['messages'])
        if (allPages is True):     
            while 'nextPageToken' in response:
                page_token = response['nextPageToken']
                response = service.users().messages().list(userId=userID, labelIds=labelList, pageToken=page_token,maxResults=500, fields="threads(id),nextPageToken").execute()
                if 'messages' in response:
                    messages.extend(response['messages'])

        if reverseOrder is True: 
            messages.reverse()

        self.GLogger.info("Successfully searched emails with labelList (" + str(labelList)+ ") and userID (" +str(userID)+ "). Number of matching emails (" +str(len(messages))+ ")")

        return messages
    except:
        self.GLogger.error("An error was encounrtered while searching for messages with google API and label list")
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        self.GLogger.exception(tb)
        return False
```

Send Email:

```
def gmailAPISendEmail(self, message, userID="me"):
    try:
        service = self.gmailAPIService
        self.GLogger.info("Attempting to send email message")
        response = (service.users().messages().send(userId=userID, body=message).execute())
        responseID = str(response['id'])
        self.GLogger.info("Successfully sent email message with ID (" + responseID +")")
        return responseID
    except:
        self.GLogger.error("Failed to send email message")
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        self.GLogger.exception(tb)
        return False
```

Message List:

```
def gmailAPIMessageLabelSearch(self, labelList, userID="me", allPages=False, reverseOrder=False, numPages=None):
    try:
        self.GLogger.info("Attempting to search emails with labelList (" + str(labelList)+ ") and userID (" +str(userID)+ ")")
        service = self.gmailAPIService
        if service is None:
            logging.error('Gmail Service not initialized')
            return False
        #response = service.users().messages().list(userId=userID, labelIds=labelList, fields='messages(id)').execute()
        response = service.users().messages().list(userId=userID, labelIds=labelList, maxResults=500, fields="messages(id),nextPageToken").execute()
        messages = []
        if 'messages' in response:
            messages.extend(response['messages'])
        numPages_Processed = 0
        if (allPages is True):     
            while 'nextPageToken' in response:
                page_token = response['nextPageToken']
                #response = service.users().messages().list(userId=userID, labelIds=labelList, pageToken=page_token, fields='messages(id)', maxResults=500).execute()
                response = service.users().messages().list(userId=userID, labelIds=labelList, pageToken=page_token, maxResults=500, fields="messages(id),nextPageToken").execute()
                if 'messages' in response:
                    messages.extend(response['messages'])
                    numPages_Processed = numPages_Processed + 1
                if (numPages is not None) and numPages_Processed>=numPages:
                    break


        if reverseOrder is True: 
            messages.reverse()

        self.GLogger.info("Successfully searched emails with labelList (" + str(labelList)+ ") and userID (" +str(userID)+ "). Number of matching emails (" +str(len(messages))+ ")")
        listToReturn = list()
        for message in messages:
            listToReturn.append(message['id'])
        return listToReturn
    except:
        self.GLogger.error("An error was encounrtered while searching for messages with google API and label list")
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        self.GLogger.exception(tb)
        return False
```

Attachment Download:

```
def gmailAPIDownloadAttachments(self, messageID, message=None, userID="me"):
    try:
        service = self.gmailAPIService
        self.GLogger.info("Attempting to download attachments from messageID (" +str(messageID)+ ")")
        if message is None: 
            message = self.gmailAPIGetFullMessage(messageID, userID=userID)
            if message is False:
                self.GLogger.error("Failed to extract message (" +str(messageID)+ ") for downloading attachments")
                return False
        attachmentList = list()
        payload = message['payload']
        if 'parts' in payload:
            parts = payload['parts']
            for part in parts:
                if part['filename']:
                    if 'data' in part['body']:
                        data = part['body']['data']
                    else:
                        att_id = part['body']['attachmentId']
                        att = service.users().messages().attachments().get(userId=userID, messageId=messageID, id=att_id).execute()
                        data = att['data']
                    file_data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data.encode('UTF-8'))
                    filename = part['filename']
                    extSearch = filename.find('.')
                    if extSearch == -1:
                        ext = ""
                        partFileName = filename[0:extSearch]
                    else:
                        ext = filename[extSearch+1:]
                        partFileName = filename[0:extSearch]

                    theAttachment = Attachment(filename,partFileName, ext, file_data)
                    attachmentList.append(theAttachment)

        self.GLogger.info("Successfully downloaded attachments from messageID (" +str(messageID)+ ")")
        return(attachmentList)
    except:
        self.GLogger.error("Encountered an error while attempting to download email attacments from messageID (" +str(messageID)+ ")")
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        self.GLogger.exception(tb)
        return False
```

Batch Requests, where searchResultParts is a list of lists, where each embedded list contains 100 message IDs:

```
for searchResultPart in searchResultParts: 
    batch = service.new_batch_http_request(callback=self.theEmailCallback)
    for msgID in searchResultPart: #Loop through each messageID
        request1 = service.users().messages().get(userId=userID,id=msgID)
        batch.add(request=request1 ,request_id=msgID) 
    batch.execute(http=self.http_toUse)
```

There are several Python Gmail API functions that I use, and these are just a subset. However, all of them tend to produce the socket.timeout error at some point. Currently, my firewall is off (ufw is inactive).

I believe I am using these functions as intended and believe this issue lies with Google. Are there any Google team members here who could take a look into this? What can I do to resolve this issue? These socket.timeout errors are occurring so often that it is causing issues with my application.

My internet connection is fiber Gigabit for both upload and download.

Edit** I am now calling all of my Python Gmail API requests through this function. It will wait 50 ms (and then 50ms more each retry) and then retry until the request succeeds or until 10 retries have been made. The socket.timeout error is still prevalent, but through my current observations, it seems like most socket.timeout errors go through after 2 or 3 retries.

```
def executeGmailAPI_withretry(self, request):
    try: 
        response_valid = False
        num_retries = 0
        while num_retries < 10: 
            try: 
                response = request.execute()
                response_valid = True
                break
            except socket.timeout:
                num_retries = num_retries + 1 
                time.sleep(0.05*num_retries)
            except: 
                self.GLogger.error("An error was encounrtered in executeGmailAPI_withretry")
                tb = traceback.format_exc()
                self.GLogger.exception(tb)
                num_retries = num_retries + 1 
                time.sleep(0.05*num_retries)

        if response_valid is False: 
            return False
        else: 
            return response
    except: 
        self.GLogger.error("An error was encounrtered in executeGmailAPI_withretry")
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        self.GLogger.exception(tb)
        return False
```